# System.TypeInitializationException error after encrypting the Connection string in web config

Tags: entity-framework, encryption, connection-string, aspnet-regiis.exe

If I dont use encryption then my application works without any error. But I am trying to encrypt Entity framework connectionstring using below given command.

> aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings"
>   "C:\SecureConStringApp"

But I am getting below error while running the application. Is there any additional steps I have to follow with Database first approach in Entity framework?

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

My connection string is given below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error resolved when I run the visual studio as an Administrator.